# if current url doesn't contain location.search redirect to home

Tags: javascript, jquery, contains, window.location

want to check if current url doesn't contains location.search do redirect to home before loading page

search page must have search location like : `example.com/s/page.html?search=some+query`

```
var home = "example.com",
searchpage="example.com/s/page.html";
```

check if current page url load

```
example.com/s/page.html
```

without `?search=some+query` redirect to home

how to translate "doesn't contains" in javascript / jquery

```
 var search = window.location.search;
  if(window.location.href!=search) {
window.location.href=home;
});
```

I know that's wrong

hope to redirect before page load content

thanx alot in advance

Comment: `hope to redirect before page load content` with javascript? You know it is client-side, it will work after page loads

Comment: Can't you just check `if (!location.search) { redirect }` ?

Comment: @u_mulder OK no problem about redirect after

Comment: @dfsq thanx  if (!location.search) { window.location.href=home; } it works but have aproblem it load example.com/S/example.com there is wrong if no i must review my code

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var curLocation= location.href;

if(curLocation.search("search") >= 0 ) {
     window.location.href=home;
};
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/h8nz544e/)